# PHP 7: Unicode escape syntax doesn't work on single quotes

Tags: php, string, unicode, php-7

Whenever strings are set with single quotes the unicode doesn't get decoded but the unicode does get decoded when set with double quotes.

How do I get the strings set by single quotes also to be decoded?

PHP

```
$poo = '\u{1F6BB}';
echo $poo;
$poo = "\u{1F6BB}";
echo $poo;
```

OUTPUT

\u{1F6BB}

Example

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a38e972226a6271996f512363c19332dae0b760

Comment: Why not just use double quotes?

Comment: The unicode syntax doesn't work on data pulled from the database but works when echoed the same data with double quotes on.

Comment: So wrap the output in double quotes?

Comment: Re wrapping a string?

Comment: I guess I still don't understand why you can't just use double quotes. I don't think it's possible with single quotes.

Comment: How do I force mysql to use double quotes?

Comment: Side question: Where could I get such Unicode characters? I need to use them like icons.

Comment: @SaidbakR http://getemoji.com/ here you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of single-quoted strings is that they *don't* support escape characters.

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) says this very clearly:

> All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

Comment: How do I get it working though? I am retrieving unicodes from mysql database and they are not being decoded..

Comment: @MeghGandhi: That's a completely different question.  Why do you have encoded strings in a database? That's almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: The database didn't support unicode and there was no way I could change it so using encoded strings was the only option left..

Comment: @MeghGandhi: Then you should use the inverse of whatever you used to encode the strings.  And make sure to handle user input that contains backslashes.

Comment: I din't get you exactly?

Comment: How are you encoding the strings?

Comment: Converting unicode characters to unicode strings, should we move to chat?