# MySQL issue with LIKE statement; JSON encoded content cannot be queried if there are specific Latin characters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an issue with Laravel 5.6.39 but I believe it is related to MySql because when I try raw SQL query it works in some cases.

I tried with raw SQL query:

```
// not working but should 
->where('column', 'LIKE', '%' . 'Za vjen\u010danja' . '%')

// working but it is interesting because example above doesn't work
->where('column', 'LIKE', '%' . 'Za vje' . '%')
```

In the database array is encoded to JSON:

```
// initial array
$array = ['Za vjenčanja'];

// retrieved raw from database 
$raw = '["Za vjen\u010danja"]';
```

It seems that characters like č, ć, ž, etc. are encoded and then query doesn't work but with basic characters from the English alphabet, it works.

*edit
I think this question is not duplicate, everything is set up out of the box. Laravel will do all encoding setup. Column type used for this is **TEXT** **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**

Comment: Both of them shouldn't work (correctly). `whereRaw()` is used as `whereRaw("column LIKE '%searchValue%'")` or as `whereRaw("column LIKE ?", ["%searchValue%"])`.

Comment: My mistake, I will correct examples @PaulSpiegel

Comment: What is the collation and charset of your column in mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @MihirBhende I answered in edit

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I think this question is not duplicate. I cannot find this issue related with Laravel

Comment: Well.. I removed my vote. But I'm still sure, you wouldn't have this issue, if *everything* is configured to use UTF-8.

Comment: However you should provide an MCVE: CREATE TABLE statement, INSERT statement and query builder select-where code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088086/php-7-unicode-escape-syntax-doesnt-work-on-single-quotes

Single quote PHP strings apparently do not support escape sequences

Comment: Another way to troubleshoot that problem is by enabling MySQL query logging, so you could see for sure what is coming in. I suspect it's literally `\u010`

Comment: @tiguchi I will try with query logging but the problem is it stores encoded string so when I try for example `... LIKE "%\u010%"` it returns nothing